# Google API doesn't return data for ISBN

Tags: api, google-api, google-books

I am using the Google API to search for books by ISBN.

I am trying with these 3 codes

```
0716604892, 0716604892, 0544506723
```

like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0716604892
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0716604892
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0544506723
```

but the last one doesn't return anything when the book exists, and the ISBN code is right.

Why is that?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Having a similar issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISBN` in uppercase.

type it as:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=ISBN:0544506723
```

instead of:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0544506723
```

Comment: but another problem occurs with google apis while using ISBN in uppercase...for some isbn numbers it sends information for multiple books even though the isbn is different.. where either only one of them is unique or the same book with different edition.. r